# Domains which random people cannot register?

Tags: domains, domain-registration

Are there any TLDs under which some random person cannot just go and register a domain by visiting the website of a domain registrar and clicking add to cart?

Something which there is a process and verification of some sort of criteria to be fulfilled that is required in order to obtain a domain.

Some random dude is not gonna get `.edu`, `.gov` or `.mil` domain. What else TLDs are there that are restricted?

Example criteria:

- Must be a public institution
- Must be a registered company
- Must be a registered organization
- Must have served in the military
- Must have a PhD degree
- Must have provided identification
- Must be a certain kind of business (such as a bar, cafe, gym, etc)

Comment: For context, this is related to this other question: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/261732/what-tlds-are-safe-to-whitelist/261733

Comment: .com.au you must be a registered Australian business

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any TLDs under which some random person cannot just go and register a domain by visiting the website of a domain registrar and clicking add to cart?

Some of them, but it varies over time, and how will you control that anyway? (Will you read the T&C of each and every TLD out there, there are more than 1500 of them...) It would be foolish to try to maintain such a list, guaranteed to be already wrong once written.

Brand TLDs for one, from ICANN 2012 new gTLD round, are obviously "closed" to only the brand owner.

No matter what you are trying to achieve, this (filtering on "restrictive" TLDs) does not seem to be the path to follow.